# Autostart jar in non-headless mode via rc.local

Tags: java, 16.10, openjdk, autostart

### What I want to accomplish

I want to start a Java jar every time I log in / the pc starts. Therefore I'm using rc.local. I reactivated it, so that it executes the scripts in `/etc/rc.local` on start (tested it, the service works great).

---

### The Problem

I want to launch the jar, I'm receiving a `HeadlessException` or `Exception in thread "main" java.awt.AWTError: Can't connect to X11 window server using ':0.0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable.`

I'm using the following script (content of rc.local)

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

java -jar -Djava.awt.headless=false /home/myusernamehere/path/to/jar/theJar.jar
exit 0
```

When I remove the `-Djava.awt.headless=false` paramaeter, I receive the HeadlessException.

So, how to fix this? Is there another good way to start a jar (*as root user*) on system start?

---

### Some other specs

- Ubuntu version: 16.10
- Java version: openjdk version "1.8.0_111"

---

### Related and things I've tried

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5362512/unable-to-run-java-gui-programs-with-ubuntu (Already installed "correct" jdk)
- Setting the headless parameter to `true` -> The jar throws HeadlessException